# Can docker-compose.yml read database connection from laravel .env file?

Tags: laravel, docker, docker-compose, environment-variables

My folder structure looks like this

```
- root-dir
-- docker
-- src //contains laravel application
---.env
-- docker-compose.yml
```

As you might know in both laravel .env and docker-compose.yml files you need to specify the connection settings to db

```
// .env
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=homestead
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret

// docker-compose.yml
environment:
   - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret
   - MYSQL_DATABASE=homestead
   - MYSQL_USER=homestead
   - MYSQL_PASSWORD=secret
```

Is there a way where I can make docker-compose to "read" the settings from the .env file, since the last one is not tracked by git? so basically if I have to change settings I have to do it only in one file and also to not track the credentials on git for docker-compose.yml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like(From docker documentation https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#the-env-file):

The “.env” file
You can set default values for any environment variables referenced in the Compose file, or used to configure Compose, in an environment file named .env:

```
$ cat .env
TAG=v1.5

$ cat docker-compose.yml
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    image: "webapp:${TAG}"
```

You can also use:

The “env_file” configuration option
You can pass multiple environment variables from an external file through to a service’s containers with the ‘env_file’ option, just like with docker run --env-file=FILE ...:

```
web:
  env_file:
    - web-variables.env
```